# Is making VPN and selling to people in different countries haraam?

Tags: halal-haram, business

I am planning to make vpn and sell them, but want to make sure it is halaal, as I want to avoid haraam money as mush as possible so wondering if it is permissible?

Reason behind making VPN is for the privacy of the people in this era of surveillance.
Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

I see no reason why VPN would be Haraam. It can be used for haraam activities, but it has many legitimate uses as well.

I am not a scholar of Islam. However I simply cannot imagine a scholar ruling against it.

Whether it is legal or illegal is a different issue.